# What is the script to run multiple macro files in Teraterm?

Tags: linux, shell-script, command-line

I'm using Teratem to log the data of a server.
For that, I need to run multiple macros, which have several Unix commands embedded in those macros.
Currently, I need to go to, 'Control->Macro->Choose the Macro' in every Teraterm window to run all the macros and I need to do this one by one.
So, can you guys tell one script or command to run all the macros at one shot?

Comment: [Tera Term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tera_Term) might be open-source but it's still a Windows-only product. This question is off-topic on Unix/Linux. You can try https://superuser.com/ (and delete it here). If instead you focused on the (Unix/Linux) problem to solve and not on how to solve it (using TeraTerm features), the question could become on-topic. I mean this could be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378).

Comment: This question is off topic, since Teraterm is not a unix/linux software.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is about Windows software.

Answer (score 0):

; Run Tera Term and open SSH session
connect 'myserver /ssh'

; Run Tera Term and open SSH1 session
connect 'myserver /ssh /1'

; Run Tera Term and open SSH2 session
connect 'myserver /ssh /2'

; Run Tera Term,open SSH session and do not prompt for user name and password
connect 'myserver /ssh /auth=password /user=username /passwd=password'

; Run Tera Term, open SSH1 session and do not prompt for user name and password
connect 'myserver /ssh /1 /auth=password /user=username /passwd=password'

; Run Tera Term, open SSH2 session and do not prompt for user name and password
connect 'myserver /ssh /2 /auth=password /user=username /passwd=password'

; Run Tera Term, open SSH session and, not prompt for user name and password and use private key file
connect 'myserver /ssh /auth=publickey/user=username /passwd=password /keyfile=private-key-file'

; Run Tera Term, open SSH1 session and, not prompt for user name and password and use private key file
connect 'myserver /ssh /1 /auth=publickey/user=username /passwd=password /keyfile=private-key-file'

; Run Tera Term, open SSH2 session and, not prompt for user name and password and use private key file
connect 'myserver /ssh /2 /auth=publickey /user=username /passwd=password /keyfile=private-key-file'

In these examples parameters shown with Italic font have to be replaced with their actual values.
The password can contain space character. To represent space inside the password replace it with '@' character. If '@' character itself is part of the password than it has to be replaced with 2 consecutive '@' characters '@@'.
Please remember that entering actual username and password in Tera Term macro will cause them to be stored as an open text and it is your responsibility to keep such macro is secure location.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: The answer's unclear. For example there are no parameters shown with italic font. Another unclear thing is that you don't indicate whether these steps must _all_ be taken one by one, or if they are different ways to achieve the same result. If the former, you could [edit](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/734772/edit) the question and create a numbered list. But before doing that - this question is not about running scirpts on a *NIX system but scripting TeraTerm,  a Windows application; therefore [off-topic](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) on Unix&Linux.